# Como faço para popular um arraylist<Tipo> com um resultado trazido do banco de dados mysql, utilizando Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Em muitos tópicos eu vejo um trecho de código que não consigo reproduzir:

```
 Query query = session.createQuery()
```

não consigo criar esse objeto session tendo como opção o método createQuery().
Alguém pode me mostrar um exemplo de como popular um ArrayList utilizando Hibernate?

Valeu galera!

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso voce ja precisa ter seu projeto configurado com os pacotes do hibernate.

A partir dai voce pode seguir esse pequeno exemplo:
Crie uma classe utilitaria:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
}

}
```

Agora crie uma para testar:

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :code");
    query.setParameter("code", "7277");
    List list = query.list();
}
}
```